# rails ActionView::MissingTemplate ajax function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I call a Rails controller function with an ajax request. It works But I got an error back:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate
```

Controller funktion is:

```
# Aktiviert einen Kurs. Diese Action wird von einem AJAX-Aufruf aus    aufgerufen
 def activate
    @course = Course.find params[:id]
    return false unless check_authorization @course
   @course.active = params[:active]
   @course.save

   redirect_to :back
end
```

ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
       url: '<%= url_for(:controller => "courses", :action => "activate_lesson") %>',
       data: {"id": <%= lesson.id%>, "active": 0}
                })
                        .done(function () {
                            saved();
                        })
                        .fail(function () {
                            notsaved();
                        })
```

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Why you are using `redirect_to :back` in controller?

Comment: I though that could help ... but no change If it is there or not

Comment: `redirect_to :back` wouldn't help `render json: { data: 12}` will work.. This is the syntax.. to return response to the Ajax caller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render `json` from your controller.

```
before_filter :authorized?, :only => :activate

def activate
  @course.active = params[:active]
  if @course.save
    render :json => {:status => :ok}
  else
    render :json => {:errors => @course.errors}
  end
end

def authorized?
  @course = Course.find params[:id]
  render :json => {:status => 401, :error => :unauthorized} unless check_authorization(@course)
end
```

Comment: I've also tried this solution but I got the same error as well

Comment: Ah! you are making call to `activate_lesson` action. Is it different than `activate` action?

Comment: thanks thats the hint I needed ^^ I have to update the activate lesson action!

Answer (score 2):

When you use action inside controller, if you do not say what specific template it should render it searches for

`app/views/controller_name_without_word_controller/action_name.html.*`

In your case it is searching for `app/views/controller_name/activate.html.*` to render it, but you do not have that file.

Solution is to return `json` response, because you are using `ajax`, but you can return `html`

You can write:

```
 def activate
   @course = Course.find params[:id]
   return false unless check_authorization @course
   @course.active = params[:active]
   @course.save
   render json: @course # or whatever you want to return
end
```

Comment: thanks but I got same error as well ... nothing changed